# recording user input to string array from editLine

Tags: c++, qt

Building a simple GUI in QT. I want to collect a list of strings every time a user inserts a name from the insert button. I got the raw logic to work for cli, however it is not the same when I convert logic to QT/C++ because the program just closes forcefully. I am using lineEdit from the input widgets. What am I doing wrong and what could have been a better alternative?

CLI Logic:

```
std::cout<<"Enter a name\tor enter nothing to quit"<<std::endl
<<">>>"; 
getline(std::cin, getNames);
listOfNames[enteredNames] = getNames;

while(getNames.length() > 0){
    enteredNames++;

    std::cout<<"Enter another name\tor enter nothing to quit"<<std::endl
    <<">>>"; 
    getline(std::cin, getNames);
    listOfNames[enteredNames] = getNames;
}
```

QT Logic:

```
void MainWindow ... buttonClicked(){
  v.namesEntered = 0;
  v.listOfNames[50]={0};

  v.getNames = ui->nameInputBox->text().toStdString();
  while(v.getNames.length() > 0){
    v.namesEntered++;
    v.listOfNames[v.namesEntered] = v.getNames;
  }
}
```

In case you are wondering the dot notations on v data is because I made a structure in mainwindow.h and needed my variables to be global for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show what `v.listOfNames` is declared as, but it like a static array, is that right?  You should use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

In any case, in your QT code, your `while` loop runs endlessly if the user enters a non-blank string, since you don't modify `v.getNames` so that its `length()` can decrease over time. You probably don't need the `while` loop at all if the user can enter only 1 string per button click.

Also, you are incrementing `namesEntered` too soon, and not validating when `namesEntered` exceeds the bounds of `listOfNames` if it is indeed a static array.

Try something more like this instead:

CLI

```cpp
enteredNames = 0;
...
std::cout << "Enter a name\tor enter nothing to quit" << std::endl << ">>>"; 
while (getline(std::cin, getNames) && !getNames.empty())
{
    listOfNames[enteredNames] = getNames;
    ++enteredNames;

    std::cout << "Enter another name\tor enter nothing to quit" << std::endl << ">>>"; 
}
```

QT

```cpp
void MainWindow ... initialize(){
    v.namesEntered = 0;
}

void MainWindow ... buttonClicked(){
    v.getNames = ui->nameInputBox->text().toStdString();
    if (!v.getNames.empty()) {
        if (v.namesEntered >= std::size(v.listOfNames)) {
            // the list is full, do something else ...
        }
        else {
            v.listOfNames[v.namesEntered] = v.getNames;
            v.namesEntered++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These alternatives work, thank you!, and responding to your question, the listOfNames is a string type array.